# "colon expected" javascript error on ajax call in IE

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using Knockout JS and have the following method that makes an ajax call. Recently I've noticed a console error `Expected ':'`, occurring on Internet Explorer 11. This works fine in Chrome. Is there something in particular here that IE can't handle correctly?

```
app.getAutoGeneratedSubmissionAttachments = function (carrierId, employerId, formId, submissionTypeId, IsMedical, IsDental, IsLife, IsVision, callBack) {
    $.ajax({
        url: $('#GetAutoGeneratedSubmissionAttachments').data('url'),
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { IsMedical, IsDental, IsVision, IsLife, carrierId: carrierId, employerId: employerId, formId: formId, submissionTypeId: submissionTypeId },
        success: function (data) {
            callBack(data);
        },
        fail: function (data) {
            $.unblockUI();
            toastr.error("An error has occured on the server when retrieving additional submission documents.");
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shorthand object properties (eg:`let o = {a, b, c}`) are an ES6 feature, not supported on IE11

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

https://caniuse.com/#search=es6

To fix it, change your data to use the standard `key: value` notation.

```
    data: { IsMedical: IsMedical, IsDental: IsDental, IsVision: IsVision, IsLife: IsLife, carrierId: carrierId, employerId: employerId, formId: formId, submissionTypeId: submissionTypeId },
```

Comment: Perfect! You've made my day, friend.